# white space at the bottom of the page

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

I have a huge amount of white space at the bottom of my page. I have no idea why. I've tried adjusting the margins and the padding on the the body and the white space isn't getting smaller.I'm encountering an issue where my web page has an excessive amount of white space at the bottom, even after attempting to adjust margins and padding for the body element. I've inspected the elements using browser developer tools but haven't been able to identify the root cause.

```js
var chatResponseBox = document.getElementById('chat-response-box');
var mainBg = document.getElementById('main-bg');
var userInput = document.getElementById('user-input');


$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#send-btn").click(async function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData();
    const userInput = document.getElementById('user-input').value;
    if (userInput == null || userInput == "") {
      Swal.fire({
        icon: 'error',
        title: 'Oops!!!',
        text: "Please enter some text!",
        allowOutsideClick: false,
        allowEscapeKey: false,
        confirmButtonColor: "#000"
      });
    } else {
      chatResponseBox.classList.remove('d-none');
      mainBg.style.display = "none";
      formData.append('prompt', userInput);
      var html = `
                              <div class="row mb-5">
                                  <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
                                  <div class="col-sm-9 text-end">
                                      <div class="row">
                                          
                                          <div class="col-sm-11 bg-human shadow rounded-3">
                                              <h6 class="p-3 text-white mb-0">` + userInput + `</h6>
                                          </div>
                                          <div class="col-sm-1">
                                              <img src="../static/assets/images/me-avatar.png" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
                                          </div>
                                      </div>
                                  </div>
                                  
                              </div>

                              <div id="loader">
                                  <div class="row">
                                      <div class="col-sm-9">
                                          <div class="snippet" data-title="dot-flashing">
                                          <div class="stage">
                                              <div class="dot-flashing"></div>
                                          </div>
                                          </div>
                                      </div>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                  `;

      chatResponseBox.innerHTML += html;
      document.getElementById('user-input').value = '';
      let response = await fetch('/chat_response', {
        method: "POST",
        body: formData
      });
      processChatResponse(response);
    }

  });
});

async function processChatResponse(response) {
  switch (response.status) {
    case 400:
      Swal.fire({
        icon: 'error',
        title: 'Oops!!!',
        text: "Sorry, Couldn't be able to generate your response now. Please try after some time.",
        confirmButtonColor: "#040b14"
      })
      break;
    case 200:
      var json = await response.json();
      var chatResult = json.answer.replace("\n", "<br>");
      var sourceDocumentList = json.source_documents_list
      var html = `
                          <div class="row mb-5">
                              <div class="col-sm-9 text-start">
                                  <div class="row">           
                                      <div class="col-sm-1">
                                          <img src="../static/assets/images/bot-avatar.png" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
                                      </div>                             
                                      <div class="col-sm-11 bg-maroon shadow rounded-3">
                                          <h6 class="p-3 text-white mb-4">` + chatResult + `</h6>`
      if (sourceDocumentList.length > 0) {
        html += `                        
                                              <div class="row p-3">
                      
                          
                                                  <div class="col-sm-9">
                                                      <a class="p-2 btn bg-white text-dark w-100" href="../static/` + sourceDocumentList[0] + `" target="_blank">` + extractFilename(sourceDocumentList[0]) + `</a>.
                                                  </div>
                                                  <div class="col-sm-3">
                                                      <span class="p-2 btn bg-white text-dark w-100">Page Number: ` + json.page_number_list[0] + `</span>.
                                                  </div>
                          
                                              </div>`
      }
      html += `                        
                                      </div>
                                      
                                  </div>
                              </div>                                
                              <div class=" col-sm-3"></div>
                          </div>
                  `;
      var loader = document.getElementById('loader');
      loader.remove();
      chatResponseBox.innerHTML += html;
      break;
    default:
      Swal.fire({
        icon: 'error',
        title: 'Oops!!!',
        text: "There is a " + response.status + " error. Please contact admin for support.",
        confirmButtonColor: "#040b14"
      })
  }
}

userInput.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
  // If the user presses the "Enter" key on the keyboard
  if (event.key === "Enter") {
    // Cancel the default action, if needed
    event.preventDefault();
    // Trigger the button element with a click
    document.getElementById("send-btn").click();
  }
});

var extractFilename = (path) => {
  const pathArray = path.split("/");
  const lastIndex = pathArray.length - 1;
  return pathArray[lastIndex];
};
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu:wght@300;400;500;700&display=swap');
* {
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
}

.sidebar-bg {
  background-color: #141B2A;
}

.main-bg {
  background-color: #111827;
}

input[type="text"],
.input-group-text {
  background-color: #374151 !important;
  border: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
}

input[type="text"] {
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
  font-family: 600 !important;
}

.input-group-text {
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
}

.input-group {
  border: 1px solid #9ca3af !important;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

input::placeholder {
  color: #9ca3af !important;
  opacity: 1;
  font-family: 600 !important;
}

.fa-solid {
  color: #606977;
}

#main-bg {
  height: 750px;
  padding-top: 20%;
}

#chat-response-box {
  height: 750px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.cursor-pointer {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.avatar {
  height: 40px;
}

.bg-bot {
  background-color: #141b2a;
  border: 1px solid #9ca3af;
}

.bg-human {
  background-color: #374151;
  border: 1px solid #9ca3af;
}

.text-grey {
  color: #9ca3af;
}

.snippet {
  position: relative;
  background: #111827;
  padding: 32px 5%;
  margin: 24px 0;
}

.stage {
  position: relative;
}

.dot-flashing {
  position: relative;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #9ca3af;
  color: #9ca3af;
  animation: dot-flashing 1s infinite linear alternate;
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
}

.dot-flashing::before,
.dot-flashing::after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.dot-flashing::before {
  left: -15px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #9ca3af;
  color: #9ca3af;
  animation: dot-flashing 1s infinite alternate;
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.dot-flashing::after {
  left: 15px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #9ca3af;
  color: #9ca3af;
  animation: dot-flashing 1s infinite alternate;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes dot-flashing {
  0% {
    background-color: #9ca3af;
  }
  50%,
  100% {
    background-color: rgba(156, 163, 175, 0.2);
  }
}

.logout-button {
  text-decoration: none !important;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-4bw+/aepP/YC94hEpVNVgiZdgIC5+VKNBQNGCHeKRQN+PtmoHDEXuppvnDJzQIu9" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-2 sidebar-bg vh-100 text-white">
        <div class="sidebar p-3">
          <p class="h2"> Petcare AI</p>
          <a class="fixed-bottom h5 text-white logout-button p-5" href="/logout">Logout<i class="fa-solid fa-right-from-bracket ms-3 text-white"></i></a>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-10 main-bg vh-100 text-white">
        <div class="main-content">
          <div class="container pt-5">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
                <div class="card border-0 p-5 bg-transparent">
                  <div id="main-bg">
                    <div class="text-center">
                      <p class="display-2"></p>
                      <p class="text-white display-5">Petcare AI</p>
                      <h5 class="text-grey">Your One-stop Solution for your Little Fur Baby</h5>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div id="chat-response-box" class="d-none">

                  </div>
                </div>
                <div id="chat-input-box" class="pt-5">
                  <div class="input-group mb-3 shadow">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control text-white p-3" name="user-input" id="user-input" aria-describedby="send-btn" placeholder="Ask Anything">
                    <span class="input-group-text cursor-pointer" id="send-btn"><i class="fa-solid fa-paper-plane"></i></span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-HwwvtgBNo3bZJJLYd8oVXjrBZt8cqVSpeBNS5n7C8IVInixGAoxmnlMuBnhbgrkm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/1da99de032.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
```

I tried changing padding, but it did not work

Comment: Please take a read of the "*[mcve]*" guidelines, with a particular focus on the "minimal" aspect of the requirement. I do - genuinely! - appreciate that you had the foresight to provide code, but it seems unlikely that so much code is necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Looks like `#main-bg` with `height: 750px; padding-top: 20%;` is the main culprit ...?

Comment: Besides `#main-bg` try changing the padding to `p-1` in `<div class="card border-0 p-5 bg-transparent">` .

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because of the height of one of the elements `<div id="main-bg">`.

The height is hardcoded and might not work for all screens. This causes the **Ask Anything** search box to go outside the viewport leading to the extra white space.

Removing the height attribute removes the white space and makes the page look like below image.

[image: result with fixes]

Comment: It's functional, but when I input the message, it continues to occupy additional space.